# How to set encoding for Jupyter Notebook in R?

Tags: r, character-encoding, jupyter-notebook

Simple question, but I can't find an answer for R. I found it for Python, but I didn't test it.

When I put to input line of the notebook: `setOption(encoding = "Windows-1250")` nothing exactly happens. I know (from Python review) I should save it to environment somehow, but how? I created Jupyter Notebook (my first time) from Anaconda by launching button, previously installed all dependencies. Everything's ok (Windows 7).

It's a problem with plotting my locale characters in plots. And maybe, I should encode my characters directly to unicode notation? Like: u003d? But it's time consuming. Any suggestions?